# Correct way to import a script / module / component into a page in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, export, nuxt.js

I'm new to js, vue & nuxt so quite confused about what is the correct and best way to import a script / module / component into an HTML page and run it.

For example, I know that this works with an event listener in the js script:

```
<template>
<div>
<button id="importJS">Go!</button>
</div>
<template>

<script src="~/index.js"></script>
```

But is something like this better?:

```
@import "~/index.js"

<template>
<div>
<button id="importJS">Go!</button>
</div>
<template>
```

And / or should only the main function be exported as a module / component something like this?:

```
module.exports = JSexport;
```

With then an import like this?:

```
<JSexport />
```

Or like this?:

```
<JSexport></JSexport>
```

In summary, my question is what is the canonical way and why is that the case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. If you create a page or a component then you have got a structure like this:

You always go following:

1. Template
2. Script
3. style

```
<template>
    <div class="some_div"> {{ page_name }} </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            page_name: "test page"
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.some_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
</style>
```

To import some other component or script you will need to use `import` inside the script tags

```
<script>
import someScript from "from/some/path/script.js";
import someComponent from "@/components/someComponent.vue";
export default {
   data(){
      return {
         page_name: "test page"
      }
   },
   components: {
      someComponent // dont forget to register your component after you import it
   }
}
</script>
```

After this you can use ur component / script inside your page/component what else.
After you have registered your imported component you can use it inside your HTML markup:

```
<template>
   <div class="some_div"> 
      {{ page_name }}
      <some-component></some-component>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a few questions. (1) In the first example, has page_name been globally exported so any other page can run {{ page_name }} too? (2) In the second example, is someScript just a variable to be instantiated with the entire script.js or is it just a function within that script? Finally, (3), would script.js also have to export itself as a component before it could be imported?

Comment: 1. `page_name` is an property/variable that is only available on this page/component and its not global.
2 . It depends what you export in your `script.js` if you, for example, export an function like `export default function() {}` then `someScript` will be an function like 
3. you need to export your script so that you can import it somewhere else `.js` are scripts `.vue` are components. here are few ways how to export `.js` files https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: the `style` is global, if you want your styling to be only available only for this page / component then you need the `scoped` attribute like this. `<style scoped>`

Comment: From the mozilla link I tried export { myFunction }; in index.js but got this error: "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-0!./index.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&' Is this something specific to Nuxt meaning it always must be export default?

Comment: If you want to export an single function use `export default function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm fall in love with vue for their documentation, the official page is awesome.

You can find all official answers to your questions in the [Vue Style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-file-component-top-level-element-order-recommended). It has a lot of examples about what is good or bad to do:

[image: Single file component Top-level order]