# How do you import three.js OBJLoader in Nuxt.js? "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js, objloader

Total noob, need help.

System: Win 10. Browser Chrome. Framework: Nuxt, default configs

I installed three.js through npm (via gitbash) with `npm install three --save`. It is in the package.json dependencies as `"three": "^0.116.1",`. I have a scene.json file saved in ~/assets/ that was generated using the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) > export scene.

I get the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" with or without `type="module"`

Here is the Vue component I'm using: *(It is rendered client-only.)*

```html
<template>
  <div id="Three">
    <div id="threeContainer"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="module">
import * as Three from 'three'
import OBJLoader from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js'

export default {
  name: 'Three',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init()
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      const container = document.getElementById('threeContainer')

      this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(
        70,
        container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight,
        0.01,
        10
      )
      this.camera.position.z = 1

      this.scene = new Three.Scene()

      const loader = new OBJLoader()
      loader.load(
        '~/assets/scene.json',
        function(obj) {
          this.scene.add(obj)
        },
        function(xhr) {
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
        },
        function(err) {
          console.error(err.stack)
        }
      )

      this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight)
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#threeContainer {
  height: 300px !important;
  background: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249944/correct-way-to-import-a-script-module-component-into-a-page-in-nuxt ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to transpile the three.js ES6 module files.

Add this line to the nuxt.config.js file:

```js
build:{
    transpile:["three"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! i was hunting everywhere to find a solution until i saw this.  This should be set as the answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

It was ES6 syntax. Line 6 should look like:

import **{** OBJLoader **}** from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js'

**ALSO THE REAL ANSWER:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61196076/11896841